# Is the set $ \{x \in \mathbb{R^2} | x_1 + x_2 < x_2^2 \} $ open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set $ \{x \in \mathbb{R^2} | x_1 + x_2 < x_2^2 \} $ open or closed?

This question has been confusing me for a very long time. I have tried solving it using coordinate geometry and trying to find the shortest distance between any arbitrary point x and the parabola created by $ x_1 + x_2 = {x_2}^2 $ but it just results in a huge mess. It so extremely obvious to me that the set is open when I draw a picture but I am not able to formally prove it.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the continuous function $\varphi(x_{1},x_{2})=x_{1}+x_{2}-x_{2}^{2}$, the preimage of $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: Umm, what about this function? 
I'm sorry I'm just extremely confused right now

Comment: So the set in question is exactly $\varphi^{-1}(-\infty,0)$. As $\varphi$ is continuous, the preimage of an open set is still open.

Comment: Is there any way we could prove it using the ball method, by considering a ball around an arbitrary set?

Comment: I think there is, but that makes me panic all the time.

Comment: I have not been taught continuous functions with respect to open sets so it's really hard for me to understand this method,
If you could help me out with the ball method I would really appreciate it

Comment: Let's wait if somebody could post an answer using elementary method, I would like to see so. Sorry, I can't help you.